# How is Ramanujan's recurrence relation for his nested radical solved?

Tags: recurrence-relations, nested-radicals

The Wikipedia article, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical), describes in some detail the derivation of Ramanujan's famous nested radical, $$\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}}.$$ In the Wikipedia article it provides a generalized expression: $$F(x)=\sqrt{ax+(n+a)^2+x\sqrt{a(x+n)+(n+a)^2+(x+n)\sqrt{\cdots}}}$$ where the first expression is defined for $a=0$, $n=1$, $x=2$. Taking the square root of both sides allows for the recurrence relation, $$F(x)^2=ax+(n+a)^2+xF(x+n).$$  The article then solves the relation, simply saying, "it can then be shown that" $$F(x)=x+n+a.$$ How is this kind of recurrence relation solved? I don't want to see Ramanujan's method. I want to know exactly what steps were taken to get from recurrence to no recurrence.

More importantly, can a recurrence relation be solved such as $$F(x)^2=ax+(n+a)^2+g(x)F(x+n)?$$ By all means, let $a=0$ and $n=1$ for simplification.

Comment: Knowing Ramanujan, that could well have been the proof he gave.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood: Bragging again about personally **knowing Ramanujan**, [Littlewood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Edensor_Littlewood) ? ;-$)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with functional equations, but I was able to get some seemingly meaningful results.  Someone feel free to correct if wrong.  So, clearly $$F(0)=a+n$$
Then, we can rewrite the equation as
$$F(x)=g(x)+a+n$$
With $g(0)=0$.
Now, after a substitution with $F(0)$, we find
$$F(-n)=a$$
And then plugging in again,
$$F(-n)=g(-n)+a+n=a$$
So, $g(-n)=-n$.  A fixed point! Then,
$$F(x)=x+n+a$$
Of course plugging in will confirm the results.

As for the other part of the question, I seriously doubt that this functional equation can be solved in general.  Notice how solving it depended greatly on the form of the equation.

Comment: Didn't you just go in a circle without providing any significant proof? You started with $F(x)=x+n+a$ and then went round-about, plugging in $x=0$ and so on and ended up again saying $F(x)=x+n+a$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still not clear.  The functional equation is dependent on $F(x+n)$ which is furthermore dependent on $n$.  Just setting $x$ to zero does not get to $F(0)=a+n$.  Even if you knew $n$ (like I said by all means, let $n=1$) you still wouldn't be able to get a LHS $F(x)$ in closed form this easily.

Comment: Oh wait.  I see what you did.  Let me think about this for a sec.

Comment: I see what I was thinking wrong. I +1 your answer. I'll award it when I've decided. Thanks!

Comment: I think there may be a logical flaw.  Consider your function $g(x)$.  You are saying that this function must be defined as $g(x)=x$.  But couldn't it be defined differently. For eg. it could be that $g(x)=2^x-1$. This still lets $F(0)=a+n$. I see where you were going but I think some assumptions were made.

Comment: You may be right about the assumptions but I don't think you are right about your definition of $g$. The point is that $g(-n)=-n$. The identity function namely

Comment: Okay, I guess my biggest question is, how did you see that $F(-n)=a$?

Comment: It comes from the functional equation. Plug in $-n$ for $x$. Then you will get some terms and an $F(0)$. Plug in the previous value for this and terms will cancel. Just work through it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25843/discussion-between-tylerhg-and-ty-obrien).

Comment: Okay there again. Facepalm XD. I'll continue in chat with anymore questions.

Answer (score 1):

This may be of interest to you, given the pattern to your questions, I had invented a generalization of this:

http://vixra.org/pdf/1310.0177v1.pdf

See bottom of page 1 to page 2.

The idea is that if you encounter a continuous increase between the coefficients in front of the radicals.

Then a simple test can be done to the floating additive constants (in this case the 1's) that allows you to verify if it has a good closed form.

Ramanujan's radical falls out of here as a special case, but this method doesn't directly line up with his, so it's better to say that I have a different mechanism of finding the same results as his.