# Investigation on this sequence :$A=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{...}}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know that the answer is **three** and is easy to prove that like this:
$$3=\sqrt{1+8}$$
$$ 3=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+15}}$$
$$ 3=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+24}}}$$
$$...$$
but I wanted to know if there is any direct way of calculating the answer.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar older questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/7204,  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1359873, and [some more](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csqrt%7B1%2B2%5Csqrt%7B1%2B3%5Csqrt%7B1%2B4%5Csqrt%7B…%7D%7D%7D%7D%24) ...

Comment: Your "proof" is actually not rigorous. In the same way, we can "prove" that $3 = \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1 + \dots}}}$, as $3 = \sqrt{1 + 8} = \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1 + 63}} = \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1 + 3968}}} = \dots$.

Comment: https://youtu.be/leFep9yt3JY

Comment: Similar to comment above, your method would show that $4=\sqrt{1+15}=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+221/4}}=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+48697/144}}}=\dots$, or basically any other number you choose... so clearly this approach does not work by itself.